# How can I make an if statement that is true only if it works for all i's in a loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a 2D array of consecutive integers.  My code should test if the integers in a row are all in order.  I want to write an if statement that evaluates to true only if it is true for all the i's and j's in the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<13;j++) {
        if(board[i][j]+1 == board[i][j+1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the if statement should only evaluate to true if the conditions are true for the entire loop.

Comment: If it's not true for at least one, then you can return false immediately. Otherwise, you can return true right after the nested loops.

Comment: You just need to invert your logic. Return false the first time you hit something that *doesn't* match. Return true at the end of the function, for the case where nothing didn't match.

Comment: as a side note, if you're going to loop through the entire 2D array it's best practise to not hardcode the loop conditions rather utilize `board.length` and `board[i].length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a boolean variable. If in any of the iterations of `i` and `j` the condition is not met, you invert the value of you variable, and once the for loop is finished you check your variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can instead check inequality and return false. If you make it all the way through your loop without returning false, return true.

Comment: Yes exactly. Looks like @serhiyb made the answer you described.

Comment: Since this is an answer, why would you want to post it as a comment in the first place?

Comment: @GolezTrol I wanted to write it as a suggestion - it seems the OP is unfamiliar with looping and there could be other ways that make more sense to him. You can, after all, see his selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<13;j++) {
        if(board[i][j]+1 != board[i][j+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Aren't you crossing the array boundaries at some point when you're doing this? Even if this would 'wrap' (relying heavily on an implementation detail), the very last iteration would still read an item that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, the goal was to show the approach not to fix all the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<13;j++) {
        if(board[i][j]+1 != board[i][j+1]) {  // if any item is not the same
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;  // if we get here, all items were the same
```